# Write out name of variable only if defined

Tags: etoolbox

I am trying to make a macro which writes out the text in variable if it is defined, but nothing otherwise.

In the CLS file I have the following:

```
\newcommand*{\myname}[1]{\def\@myname{#1}}
```

and later I define the following:

```
\newcommand{\writeot}{
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{
****\ifdef{\myname}{}{\@instaname}**
}**
\thispagestyle{fancy}
}
```

In TEX document I wish to be able to choose to set `\myname` or not.

When I call `\writeout`, I then want to write nothing if I have not set `\myname`, or write it out if it is set.

I have tried several options of `etoolbox` `ifdef, ifdefempty, ifvoid, ifundef`, but I can't make them work. I always have to define `\myname` in my TEX (if not compilation fails), and so it always goes to the "true option" even when it is defined as `\myname{}`.

I hope my question is clear, I am new to making my own CLS in latex,

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please make this into something others can test without having to guess half of what you are doing. Besides, I tend to use `\ifdefvoid\macro{void}{not void}`

Comment: you are testing if `\myname` is defined but it always is defined as you have defined it, as you have shown. You presumably meant to test if `\@myname` is defined, which will only be the case if `\myname` has been used.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any test, just use

```
 \fancyfoot[C]{****\@instaname**}
```

where the class defines

```
\newcommand*{\myname}[1]{\def\@instaname{#1}}
\myname{}
```

so by default the footer will be `******` but of in the document you go

```
\myname{hello}
```

then the footer will be `****hello**`